# Retrieve huge amount of data into data table and create csv file

Tags: c#-4.0, ado.net

My application calls a stored procedure and while retrieving the data from it into a data table, I am getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException"

Note: my stored procedure returns 70 million rows of data. And I need to receive all 70 million rows and write them to a `.CSV` file.

Answer (score 0):

Reading all the data at once will often lead to "outofmemory exception". Instead try to read update your CSV in batches of 1000's